# How do I patch eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, patch

Eclipse is giving me an error that has been deemed a bug some time ago and the patch is available (here: https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/16201/). The new Eclipse has this issue fixed, but I am using Nvidia Nsight, which is unfortunately is built on the old (broken) version, 3.8.

How do I patch eclipse by hand? I am not good with Linux (using Ubuntu 13.04 right now), and I'm so confused about to do with this patch. Completely out of my comfort zone.

I saw this link mentioned in one of the other posts, but I don't think it's applicable because it's for SWT: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/git.php.

So I found this page: http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php, which is where the patch is from I think. Then I navigated to the Juno page, and through "Install new software" option in eclipse and the url 'http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno" tried to patch it. This didn't seem to work (it suggested that some stuff has already been installed, and then had an error while actually doing the installation).

So now I don't know what to do at all. Help would be appreciated :(

Edit: on that same page with the CDT downloads, I went to Kepler (because on the patch page it says 8.3 is the first version it's implemented in) and tried to use that patch. The features installed, but didn't fix anything. I can't apply the C/C++ Development tools bit because  I already have Nsight and I can only have one apparently.